# Text-Based User Interface Development

Tags: user-interface, embedded, tui

Where can I find resources related to the design and development of text-based user interfaces (e.g. interfaces exported via serial port from embedded devices to VT100 terminals)? I am interested in any material available - best practices, style guides, frameworks, etc.

Note that I am asking about resources related to the design and development of '[TUIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface)' rather than command-line interfaces (the thrust of [Text User Interface Design Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324056/text-user-interface-design-reference)). Wikipedia differentiates TUIs from CLIs (and GUIs) as follows:

> TUIs are different from command-line
>   interfaces in that, like GUIs, they
>   use the entire screen area and do not
>   necessarily provide line-by-line
>   output. However, TUIs only use text
>   and symbols available on a typical
>   text terminal, while GUIs typically
>   use high-resolution graphics modes.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324056/text-user-interface-design-reference

Comment: I saw that post, Shoban. Depite its title, that question is related to the design of CLIs rather than text-based user interfaces (TUIs). I will clarify this in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any experience with VT100 and that kind of stuff, but I know that [Turbo Vision](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/) is still around and kicking on quite a few platforms, DOS and Linux included. And back in its day, it was used to write some of the better TUI applications (Borland C++ and Borland Pascal DOS IDEs come to mind), and I've seen it used in LOB applications back then quite often as well.

Screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/tv2-QNX-tvscreen.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Wow! This brings back some old memories!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps take a look at [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)? It's a GNU library specifically designed for writing terminal-based UIs.

Comment: Amazingly, there's actually a book that's been written about `ncurses` in the last couple of years (I'm actually astonished by that), and it's gotten some good reviews.

http://www.amazon.com/Programmers-Guide-NCurses-Dan-Gookin/dp/0470107596

Answer (score 3):

For best practices and style guides, the IBM Common User Access (CUA) defines a "text subset" that should be helpful especially if your users are used to GUIs. Details are in Chapter 3 of:

http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/F29BDG00/CCONTENTS

Additional CUA guidelines and standards are in:

http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/F29AL000/CCONTENTS?DT=19921204095534

Answer (score 2):

http://petesqbsite.com/sections/express/issue21/tuiseriespart1.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface

Hope it helps... I still make programs in TUI ([www.harbour-project.org](http://www.harbour-project.org))